# How to remove numerous untracked and pending changes in VS Code source control

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitignore

I have over 700 pending changes in the source control of my VS Code.

They are tracked and untracked and cannot send anything to GitHub. I tried using `git init` and `git ignore`, and read that I need to be sure my Node npm is installed globally, but don't know how to check that.

I also checked the unhide box for my folders but the changes keep adding up on VS Code. I even tried to commit them all, which didn't work as they're still there. How do I stop this?

Comment: what are the file names that are pending, use `git status` on the command line

Comment: I am now seeing over 10K some of the files are:                                                                       
                                                                                                                 
          reateAssigner.js
        new file:   .vscode/extensions/.00704cfe-6ae6-49c5-b732-b6a883561e05/dist/wallaby/node_modules/lodash/internal/createBindWrapper.js
        new file:   .vscode/extensions/.00704cfe-6ae6-49c5-b732-

Comment: Other files are:                                                                                                                                     on.py
        new file:   .vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_additional_thread_info.py
        new file:   .vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.10.1365161279/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bu

Comment: Sorry, other files are:

Comment: new file:   .vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.10.3/dist/typeshed-fallback/stdlib/asyncio/base_tasks.pyi
        new file:   .vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.10.3/dist/typeshed-fallback/stdlib/asyncio/compat.pyi
        new file:   .vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.10.3/dist/typeshed-fallback/stdlib/asyncio/constants.pyi
        new file:   .vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.10.3/dist/typeshed-fallback/stdlib/asyncio/coroutines.pyi
        new file:   .vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.10.3/dist/typeshed-

Comment: don't create a git repository in your home directory, remove the `~/.git` folder, create a subdir and execute `git init` in there, move your project files to this subdir, open the subdir of folder in VSC

Comment: Thank you so much, rioV8!!!!!  I sincerely apricate it!